# Docker container die exitCode=0

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

So I'm trying to start a Ubuntu container in Docker.

I'm running:

> Windows 10 Enterprice N version 1903
>   Docker Desktop Community version 2.1.5.0(40323) Channel edge
>   Docker version 19.03.4, build 9013bf5

I start the docker container with this simple command:

```
docker run --interactive --tty ubuntu bash
```

In the event log I get this:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> docker events
2019-11-08T11:55:03.742217968+01:00 network connect 6b42b926ed6a78543c50aa95d756e9e7ac4302e0e4046dcd81a9e20929f9bf68 (container=4ca7ea561298d74c82dd69e0394bb992f866599d05f93a68e9326eaedbf611e4, name=bridge, type=bridge)  
2019-11-08T11:55:03.981880769+01:00 container start 4ca7ea561298d74c82dd69e0394bb992f866599d05f93a68e9326eaedbf611e4 (image=ubuntu, name=mystifying_mahavira)  
2019-11-08T11:55:04.033505470+01:00 container die 4ca7ea561298d74c82dd69e0394bb992f866599d05f93a68e9326eaedbf611e4 (exitCode=0, image=ubuntu, name=mystifying_mahavira)  
2019-11-08T11:55:04.109592671+01:00 network disconnect 6b42b926ed6a78543c50aa95d756e9e7ac4302e0e4046dcd81a9e20929f9bf68 (container=4ca7ea561298d74c82dd69e0394bb992f866599d05f93a68e9326eaedbf611e4, name=bridge, type=bridge)
```

I haven't made any chances to docker other than disable "start on logon"

Comment: If you run `docker run --interactive --tty ubuntu bash -c 'echo something'` does it print `something`?

Comment: `docker run --interactive --tty ubuntu bash -c 'Echo hello world'`  
bash: Echo: command not found

Comment: It's  `echo`, all lowercase, not `Echo`.... On the other hand, this means the bash runs... This would mean the problem occurs when bash tries to read from the terminal (with this specific test, it doesn't).

Comment: TTY problems seems to be a known issue for Docker on Windows, see [the bug report](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1588), with possible workarounds?

Comment: Id tried with echo, and correct. Then it does post a 'hello world'.

I read about the tty error, and I then tried this instead: `docker run -d ubuntu` I still get the same error. Looks the exact same as mentioned above.